# Where to store publicly-accessible files

Tags: admin, security

I have built a wordpress site that requires that the users log in to be able to access the content.  However, I want to make a few files publicly-accessible.

The only clue I have found so far recommended creating a new folder under the wp-content folder, but this did not work.  E.g. http://yoursite.com/wp-content/public/readme.txt redirects to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would depend how you've made your site private?

I've used this plugin to set sites to private
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/

It also has settings to exclude any URLs from being set to private.

There are a bunch of other plugins that do similar thins.